# Encountered problems when integrating Shiro and WebSocket interfaces

Tags: websocket, shiro

As in the title, when I develop WebSocket in the Springboot project managed by Shiro, I need to get the information of the currently logged-in user in the socket interface

```
public static Subject getSubjct() {
    return SecurityUtils.getSubject();
}
```

Error in this line : SecurityUtils.getSubject();

```
org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.
at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager(SecurityUtils.java:123)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.<init>(Subject.java:626)
at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSubject(SecurityUtils.java:56)
at com.runtime.system.util.ShiroUtils.getSubjct(ShiroUtils.java:18)
at com.runtime.system.util.ShiroUtils.getUser(ShiroUtils.java:22)
```

This problem does not exist in the conventional Api interface. I feel very distressed. Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box Shiro doesn't know how to deal with the thread that is running your async request.

You will need to associate data with the async request, usually the Subject, and then execute what you need to do via a Runnable/Callable:

```java
Subject subject = <get the subject from your async context>;
subject.execute( <your runnable> );
```

See: https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#thread-association

Comment: Extremely grateful!